# Direct sum modules

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, definition, direct-sum

I am learning about direct sum of modules. It says that the direct sum of a finite number of modules is equal to the cartesian product of the modules 
$$A \oplus B = A × B = \{(a, b) :\, a ∈ A \textrm{ and } b ∈ B\}.$$ 
But I also read: 
$$A \oplus B = A + B = \{a + b :\, a ∈ A \textrm{ and } b ∈ B\} \textrm{ if } A ∩ B = \{0\}.$$ 
So which is it?

Comment: It's not a question of one or the other. The former is what is often called an "external direct sum"/"external direct product", when the two modules are just abstract modules and need not have any relation to one another. The latter is what is called an "internal direct sum"/"internal direct product", which is when $A$ and $B$ are submodules of some larger module $M$ and satisfy the condition $A\cap B=\{0\}$. The internal direct sum of $A$ and $B$ is then a submodule of $M$, and is isomorphic to the external direct sum.

Comment: Thank you for your tribute. I will learn it as a external direct sum because the book only states that.